# White space is not removing from a String

Tags: ios, swift

I am removing white space from a string with "trimmingCharacters" but space is not removing .

```
    let number = "123 456"
    let replaced = number.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
     print(username)
     print(replaced)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`** method on `String`, i.e.

```
let number = "123 456"
let replaced = number.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

print(replaced) //Output: 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String **replacingOccurrences**

```
let number = "123 456"
let replaced = number.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(replaced)
```

**or**

Use **Filter**

```
let removed = number.filter{!$0.isWhitespace}
print(removed)
```

> Output 123456